# How do you translate the timezone abbreviation in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, localization, translation

When using the PHP to return the timezone abbreviation with either `date('T')` or `strftime('%Z')` the result does not translate to the localized version of these abbreviations.

In french I have been told the following at the correct translations:

> EDT == HAE
>
> EST == HNE

I have tried the following code example:

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
echo strftime('%Z');
echo date('T');
?>
```

All attempts produce EST/EDT rather than the translated versions.

Comment: I am still a bit curious if EDT even needs to be translated then if the locale files are not translating these strings. Would be nice to have a french person chime in on the best practice for showing timezones.

Comment: "In french I have been told the following at the correct translations:" - Do you have any reference for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same on Mac and Linux.

I inspected the Gettext MO file for French, like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/msgunfmt /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/texinfo.mo
```

This shows all the translations for things like months and days.
So you should get translations if you do:

```
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y\n");
// gives "Vendredi 27 juin 2014"
```

But the translation file does not appear to contain translations for EST, or EDT - or in fact any others I looked for.

So I guess the answer is that these strings are simply not translated in the standard locale packages.